# Database version problem

Tags: go-ethereum

I found geth built from the latest master branch(`git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum.git`) uses new database version different from `Geth & Tools 1.8.27`(latest stable excutable version now).

What shall be done to fix the problem.

```
[root@localhost test]# geth --networkid 123456 --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ./enode1/data --syncmode 'full' --port "2001" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,miner,web3,net,personal,txpool"
INFO [05-28|10:50:12.097] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [05-28|10:50:12.189] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.27-stable-4bcc0a37/linux-amd64/go1.11.9
INFO [05-28|10:50:12.189] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/download/eth5/enode1/data/geth/chaindata cache=512 handles=2048
INFO [05-28|10:50:12.223] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 123456 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople: 5  ConstantinopleFix: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [05-28|10:50:12.223] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=123456
Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: database version is v6, Geth 1.8.27-stable only supports v3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to downgrade the version of the database: From a developer comment https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19693

> Whenever we make a minor version bump (e.g. from 1.8.x to 1.9.0) you can expect incompatible breaking changes that will prevent going back down. There's no way to make old versions aware of new data formats. If you want to use 18.27, you need to only use that. Once you update, there'd no going back down.

You have to resync again from scratch if you want to use a stable version 1.8.xx after updating to a master version 1.9.xx.